# format arbitrary data in CSV

Tags: python, bash, csv, kubernetes, formatting

I have a file that is arbitrary formatted as such:

```
Name:pod1
Image:image1
cpu:2
memory:1000Mi
cpu:300m
memory:1000Mi
Name:pod2
Image:image2
cpu:2
memory:1000Mi
cpu:300m
memory:1000Mi
```

it's actually a list of pods from a Kubernetes cluster.

I need to transform the data in csv like this:

```
Name,Image,cpu,memory
pod1,image1,2,1000Mi
pod1,image1,300m,1000Mi
pod2,image2,2,1000Mi
pod2,image2,300m,1000Mi
```

where the first 2 values of rows 2 and 4 repeat the first 2 values of rows 1 and 3.

I would preferably have a solution in bash with a combination of grep/sed/awk but that's me being picky. I am totally fine with any solution in Python or even Powershell.

thanks very much!

Comment: are all fields always present and is the order preserved?

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far? will the labels always be `Name`, `Image`, `cpu` and `memory`?

Comment: @Raphael - yes, always in that order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that order is fixed: when I see a "memory" line, I'll print a complete record.

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = ":"; OFS = ","; print "Name","Image","cpu","memory"}
    {record[$1] = $2}
    $1 == "memory" {print record["Name"], record["Image"], record["cpu"], record["memory"]}
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

A generic but python based solution:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

text = """Name:pod1
Image:image1
cpu:2
memory:1000Mi
cpu:300m
memory:1000Mi
Name:pod2
Image:image2
cpu:2
memory:1000Mi
cpu:300m
memory:1000Mi"""

lines = text.splitlines(keepends=False)
record = dict()
records = list()
for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):
    field, value = line.split(':')
    if field in record:
        # we have seen this field before thus this record is complete
        # and the field value pair belongs to the next record
        records.append(record)
        # create a new empty record
        record = dict()
    # set the value for the current record
    record[field] = value

dataframe = DataFrame(records)
dataframe.to_csv('here_we_go.csv', index=False)
```

Note: This solution also works with missing or unordered fields but a combination of both could break it.

Comment: "we have seen this field before thus this record is complete" -- that's smart.

Comment: question: does this emit the CSV header row?

Comment: @glennjackman yes it does (this is handled by pandas)

Answer (score 1):

As the order is always consistent, a row could be written whenever a `memory` key is seen:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=['Name', 'Image', 'cpu', 'memory'])
    csv_output.writeheader()
    block = {}
    
    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=':'):
        if len(row) == 2:   # skip blank lines
            block[row[0]] = row[1]
        
            if row[0] == 'memory':
                csv_output.writerow(block)
```

Giving:

```
Name,Image,cpu,memory
pod1,image1,2,1000Mi
pod1,image1,300m,1000Mi
pod2,image2,2,1000Mi
pod2,image2,300m,1000Mi
```